How is the automatic tools choosing implemented in LangChain?
There is a topic about building an agent in LangChain docs. It says that the following code:
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

search = TavilySearchResults(max_results=2)
tools = [search]
model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4")
model_with_tools = model.bind_tools(tools)
response = model_with_tools.invoke([HumanMessage(content="Hi!")])
print(f"ContentString: {response.content}")
print(f"ToolCalls: {response.tool_calls}")

prints out this:
ContentString: Hello!
ToolCalls: []

but if replace "Hi!" with "What's the weather in SF?"
response = model_with_tools.invoke([HumanMessage(content="What's the weather in SF?")])

i get this:
contentstring:
ToolCalls: [{'name': 'tavily_search_results_json', 'args': {'query': 'weather san francisco'}, 'id': 'toolu_01VTP7DUvSfgtYxsq9x4EwMp'}]

As you can see, the decision whether to use the tool or not is made automatically depending on the prompt.
So my question is how is it implemented? I assume that there is some sentence transformer which translates the tool description into embeddings, then translates my promt into embeddings with the same sentence transformer and put those embeddings into some local vector data base. And if the distance between my prompt and the description is small then LangChain decides to use the tool. Am i right? If it so, what exactly sentence transformer is used ?

The information you are looking, I guess, that's the secret of the commercial LLMs. How they implement Tools, agents are trade secret I believe - like the vectors and dimension spaces. No one will expose those!
In general yes, the tool description plays a part when LLM decide which tool to use in what sequence based on your question.

You can customise how/when/why TavilySearchResults calls search tool by setting the description param.
The default description used to determine whether to call search tool is:
description: str = 'A search engine optimized for comprehensive, accurate, and trusted results. Useful for when you need to answer questions about current events. Input should be a search query.'

Obviously not so great, you can change it to what you need like:
custom_description = """
Only use the search tool if:
1. The question requires current information
2. The information cannot be derived from common knowledge
3. The question indicated that the answer must be a comprehensive, accurate, and trusted result
"""

search = TavilySearchResults(
    max_results=2, 
    description=custom_description
)

Then something controllable happened. You'll notice that TavilySearchResults won't make query tool calls easily anymore unless input question meets the newly customised conditions.
API reference:
https://python.langchain.com/api_reference/community/tools/langchain_community.tools.tavily_search.tool.TavilySearchResults.html#langchain_community.tools.tavily_search.tool.TavilySearchResults.description
